# How do I concat strings from different columns and search using this expression

Tags: sql, oledb, visual-foxpro, oledbcommand

I have a lot of values like '1@1@15'
I need to build sql for DB (legasy FoxPro) request like this:

```
SELECT        ba1 AS mest, bd1 AS Ukpg, be1 AS well, be12 AS probur, be13 AS iskust, be6 AS burDate
FROM            ksmest
WHERE        ((ba1 + '@' + bd1 + '@' + be1) IN ('1@1@15', '3@1@15'))
```

ba1, bd1 and be1 is numbers (not string).

As you see, I need to concat strings from different columns and search using this expression. My request is not works, it is just a sample.
Is it possible to solve? Or may be another ways?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the relevant columns into an aggregate field in the SELECT statement, converting them to string in the process - see 'mycolumn' in this example. Also your syntax there looks more like T-SQL, for VFP you would use INLIST()

```
select ;
   ba1 AS mest, bd1 AS Ukpg, be1 AS well, be12 AS probur, be13 AS iskust, be6 AS burDate ;
   alltrim(str(ba1, 12, 0)) + "@" + alltrim(str(bd1, 12, 0)) ;
        + "@" + alltrim(str(be1, 12, 0)) as mycolumn;
from ksmest ;
where inlist(mycolumn, "1@1@15", "3@1@15")
```

Comment: Some explanations would be nice.

Comment: I have found the solution by myself, but thanks for answer! My be my method well work more slower:  `SELECT        LTRIM(STR(ba1)) + '@' + LTRIM(STR(bd1)) + '@' + LTRIM(STR(be1)) AS wid, be12 AS probur, be13 AS iskust, be6 AS burDate
FROM            ksmest
WHERE        ((ALLTRIM(STR(ba1)) + '@' + ALLTRIM(STR(bd1)) + '@' + ALLTRIM(STR(be1))) IN ('1@1@117', '1@1@141', '1@2@206')` in fact the `wid` field has a lot of spaces after last symbol, ALLTRIM cant help :)

Comment: As long as bd1 and ba1 and be1 are integers or you don't mind your wid potentially being "123.00@456.23@192.98" or similar, that will work.

Comment: You can use TRANSFORM() rather than LTRIM(STR()). I think it'll be a little faster.